# Как получить значение свойства объекта по его адресу?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Имеется экземпляр объекта и строка с текстовым представлением "адреса" свойства. Например объект выглядит так:

```cs
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
  public Address BirthPlace { get; set; }
}
public class Address {
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string Nr { get; set; }
}
```

Как получить значение свойства используя его "адрес"?
Например такой: `Person.BirthPlace.Country`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью рефлексии можно сделать так:

```cs
var person = new Person {
  Name = "James Goodwin",
  BirthDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
  BirthPlace = new Address {
    Country = "Oz",
    City = "Emerald City",
    Street = "Yellow brick road",
    Nr = "1"
  }
};

public object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName, char delimiter = '.')
{
    if (propName.Contains(delimiter))
    {
        string[] propNames = propName.Split(new char[] { delimiter }, 2);
        return GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(src, propNames[0]), propNames[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        var prop = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
        return prop?.GetValue(src, null);
    }
}

// использование:
// string propAddress = "BirthPlace.Country";
// string birthCountry = GetPropertyValue(person, propAddress);
// birthCountry = "Oz"
```

"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sNuCh7).