# Как получить тип значения свойства объекта по его адресу?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Имеется экземпляр объекта и строка с текстовым представлением "адреса" свойства объекта. Например:

```cs
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
  public Address BirthPlace { get; set; }
}
public class Address {
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string Nr { get; set; }
}
```

Как получить тип значения свойства используя его "адрес"?
Например такой: `BirthPlace.Country`?

Comment: Какой смысл делать полный [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1034806/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83) вопроса, изменив только код?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это не полный дубликат. Здесь показано, как получить ТИП значения свойства, а в другом вопросе само значение. Ни того, ни другого не нашёл на ruSO.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью рефлексии можно сделать так:

```cs
public Type GetTypeOfProperty(Type type, string propName, char delimiter = '.')
{
    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
    Type propertyType = null;
    if (propName.Contains(delimiter.ToString()))
    {
        string[] propNames = propName.Split(new char[] { delimiter }, 2);
        propertyType = type.GetProperty(propNames[0], bindingFlags)?.PropertyType;
        return GetTypeOfProperty(propertyType, propNames[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        propertyType = type.GetProperty(propName, bindingFlags)?.PropertyType;
    }
    return propertyType;
}
// Использование:
// string propAddress = "BirthPlace.Country";
// Type birthPlaceType = GetTypeOfProperty(typeof(Person), propAddress);
```

"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v4z7Ff).